Add constraints to cubic or quintic polynomial for robot arm trajectory generation
I am planing path for a robotic arm. I am using cubic/quintic polynomials for trajectory generation.
How can I add constraints to cubic or quintic polynomial such that the generated trajectory is within a region. For example in the blue colored region below:

For example if I generate a line from (3,4) to (8,5), the output line should look like the red line in the image below(means not passing through the white portion):

Thanks
